# Running a quiz for the inputted number

Tags: vb.net

I'm quite new to programming so excuse my lack of knowledge.

I'm trying to create a quiz for my project and am having trouble with it. Currently, I'm trying to make the quiz run until the number of questions is the same as the desired amount the user inputs in a Combobox from the previous form. Whilst this does partially work, the problem is that it is really slow and freezes when you click the button the second time.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class ArithmeticQuestions

    Dim NoQ = ArQOP.NoQ


    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim n As Integer = 1

    Private Sub ArithmeticQuestions_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Hide()
        RadioButton1.Hide()
        RadioButton2.Hide()
        RadioButton3.Hide()
        RadioButton4.Hide()
        SkipQues.Hide()
        NxtQues.Hide()


    End Sub

    Sub Questions()
        cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=login.accdb"
        cn.Open()
        cm.CommandText = "SELECT Questions FROM MCQ WHERE QuestionNumber ='" & n & "'"
        cm.Connection = cn
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        Label1.Text = dr.Item("Questions")
        cn.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub NxtQues_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NxtQues.Click
        n = n + 1
        Do
            Call Questions()
        Loop Until n = NoQ
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartQuiz.Click
        Label1.Show()
        RadioButton1.Show()
        RadioButton2.Show()
        RadioButton3.Show()
        RadioButton4.Show()
        SkipQues.Show()
        NxtQues.Show()
        StartQuiz.Hide()
        Call Questions()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yikes, this looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn since `n` is declared as an `integer` and user can't change , could you explain how you could inject in the above code, I'm interested to know how this *could* be done.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ You can override the default system numeric formatting in Windows to include arbitrary text for the negative sign, decimal point, or group separator. The UI only lets you pick from a list, but the actual registry setting this controls can be set to *anything*.

Comment: I seen where you can change the format, but not the actual data type, it's still a number from what I can see, didn't check the registry; great explanation.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Instead of, say, `1.0`, you can use the registry to get it to produce things like `1';DROP TABLE Questions;--0`, where all that extra text is just a fancy decimal point. There are similar issues for the negative sign and group separators. In this case, `1.0` and `-1` are not likely values, but you can also change for different cultures how often group separators are supposed to occur. The main thing is, we have parameterized queries, and they're not really any harder. _Use them._

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks for the explanation. I agree with parameterized queries fully and use them all the time, just curious as in this case, how it *could happen*. So when you change that registry value, what happens when running the app, would it even run?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ It's cool ;) In this situation, I doubt anyone would have that much motivation to actually _hack_ his little project, but what does happen all the time is as soon as an application has any real meaningful deployment size, you'll run into someone who does have a custom (non-malicious) number format doing something you didn't expect that just breaks the query.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn again thanks for the explanation, always great to hear from you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that NoQ is the number of questions the user requested.

Keep you database objects local to the method where they are used so you can control that they are closed and disposed. Using...End Using blocks take care of this for you even if there is an error. You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection and the command text and connection directly to the constructor of the command.

Always use Parameters. I had to guess at the OleDbType. Check your database for the correct type and adjust the code accordingly. It appears that you are retrieving a single piece of data so you can use .ExecuteScalar to get the first column of the first row of the result set.

In the button code I just incremented the question number and checked if against the maximum number of questions.

```
Dim NoQ = ArQOP.NoQ
Dim n As Integer

Private Sub Questions()
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=login.accdb"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Questions FROM MCQ WHERE QuestionNumber = @QuestionNumber;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuestionNumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value = n
        cn.Open()
        Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub NxtQues_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NxtQues.Click
    n += 1
    If n <= NoQ Then
        Questions()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. I used that code and got the following error: "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: To solve that all I changed was 5th line so instead of @QuestionNumber it was just & n  & "'" and making n equal 1

Comment: And I removed the 6th,